# Choose splatform-independent language for math-intensive computations

Tags: programming-languages

I am planning on making a flame fractal engine (no GUI), similar to flam3,
but I need to chose a language. I have one such engine made in Java already, but it is too slow.

What I seek is a compiled language, that can be compiled to both windows and Linux (hence no .NET, GPU language), and preferably with garbage collecting and object-orientation (so no C, and C++).

What languages out there, except D, satisfy these conditions?
Any other thoughts on this?

EDIT: I am more after what similar alternatives there is to D, since D is still in development. 
I will probably choose D, since it has native support for complex numbers, among other things.
However, C++ is more accessible to other developers, but it is a hard language, in my opinion.

Comment: IIRC, there are libraries available that provide garbage collection for C++

Comment: Why do you need full blown garbage collection? Dislike smart-pointers? Why not D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go for D, since it is closest to what I want. 
I was merely curious what other languages that were comparable to D.

Answer (score 0):

This will undoubtedly start a new flamewar until someone closes the question. My personal opinion is you should use C++, where the missing garbage collection is something you should accept, since manual memory management offers you more performance tuning options.

Google announced a research paper yesterday about a Java / C++ / Go / Scala comparison, you may find it helpful:

https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-1-Hundt.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You made yourself a very tough task (and asked an interesting question, by the way).

The only language that springs to my mind is Ada (it has an [optional garbage collector](http://www.enyo.de/fw/software/gnat-gc), as [discussed in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691059/why-doesnt-ada-have-a-garbage-collector), and according to [this book](http://www.it.bton.ac.uk/staff/je/adacraft) it support object-orientation). This [Ubuntu comparison](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org) shows that Ada 2005 is quite fast, generally faster in benchmarks than Java, but slower than C/C++.

*Disclaimer*: I do not claim that Ada is superior to any other language. In fact, I have not used it in any reasonable application. I believe using C++ will produce faster code; moreover, probably the effort required to manage the memory manually in C++ is worth the speed improvement, but I am not an expert in this. This is not to start a flamewar (as @Doc pointed out, it may happen); just my opinion on the topic.